# Permission change commands do not work for applications (revoke, grant) in ADB Shell, Terminal Emulator

Tags: permissions, shell, adb

I need to change the permissions of the application through ADB Shell. When you enter and activate a command, no errors appear, I switch to the permissions settings of the application, everything remains the same ...

I enter the following commands:

```
adb -d shell pm revoke com.myapp.test android.permission.SEND_SMS
adb -d shell pm revoke com.myapp.test android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS
adb -d shell pm revoke com.myapp.test android.permission.READ_SMS
adb -d shell pm revoke com.myapp.test android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
adb -d shell pm revoke com.myapp.test android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS
```

Device: Xiaomi Redmi 5 MIUI 10 China Stable Android 7.1.2 Device, has a ROOT

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not